# Is vectorization a hardware/framework specific feature or is it a good coding practice?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, parallel-processing, vectorization

I am trying to wrap my head around vectorization (for numerical computing), and I'm coming across seemingly contradictory explanations:

- My understanding is that it is a feature built into low-level libraries that takes advantage of parallel processing capabilities of a given processor to perform operations against multiple data points simultaneously.
- But several tutorials seem to be describing it as a coding practice that one incorporates into their code for more efficiency. How is it a coding practice, if it is also a feature you have or you don't have in the framework you are using.

A more concrete explanation of my dilemma:

- Let's say I have a loop to calculate an operation on a list of numbers in Python. To vectorize it, I just import Numpy and then use an array function to do the calculation in one step instead of having to write a time consuming loop. The low level C routines used by Numpy will do all the heavy lifting on my behalf.

Knowing about Numpy and how to import it and use it is not a coding practice, as far as I can tell. It's just good knowledge of tools and frameworks, that's all.

So why do people keep referring to vectorization as a coding practice that good coders leverage in their code?

Comment: Well while this could lead to interesting discussions I think thats not the scope for SO as this will probably lead to opinoated answers

Comment: loop is not pythonic, vectorization is faster, vectorized code is easier to read.

Comment: My 2 cents and based on my personal experience - Not sure about coding practice, but it's a practice that comes alot from parallel-thinking. Apart from it, there are tools in every environment - NumPy/MATLAB etc. that are very efficient. If we could remodel our solutions to leverage those with parallel thinking, we might benefit too. Note that its all case by case basis, because not every problem could be solved with parallel procedures. Also, memory congestion and latency plays an important role too and that's where low level C codes in NumPy or numba shines.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi, loops are very `pythonic`.  `for`, `while` and loop comprehensions are central to Python code.  In `numpy`, a package we add to `python`, we do try to avoid loops (or rather move them into compiled code).

Comment: @BjörnB probably - but there should be objective answers to my question. For example if vectorization is indeed a coding practice, then an example of regular loop and a vectorized loop that doesn't depend on packages or hardware would be an objective answer, no?

Answer (score 6):

Vectorization can mean different things in different contexts.  In `numpy` we usually mean using the compiled numpy methods to work on whole arrays.  In effect it means moving any loops out of interpreted Python and into compiled code.  It's very specific to `numpy`.

I came to `numpy` from MATLAB years ago, and APL before that (and physics/math as a student).  Thus I've been used to thinking in terms of whole arrays/vectors/matrices for a long time.

MATLAB now has a lot just-in-time compiling, so programmers can write iterative code without a performance penalty.  `numba` (and `cython`) lets `numpy` users do some of the same, though there are still a lot of rough edges - as can be seen in `numpa` tagged questions.

Parallelization and other means of taking advantage of modern multi-core computers is a different topic.  That usually requires using additional packages.

I took issue with a comment that loops are not Pythonic.  I should qualify that a bit.  Python does have tools for avoiding large, hard to read loops, things like list comprehensions, generators and other comprehensions. Performing a complex task by stringing together comprehensions and generators is good Python practice, but that's not 'vectorization' (in the numpy sense).

Answer (score 2):

Vectorization leverage the SIMD (Single Instruction Multiple Data) instruction set of modern processors. For example, assume your data is 32 bits, back in the old days one addition would cost one instruction (say 4 clock cycles depending on the architecture). Intel's latest SIMD instructions now process 512 bits of data all at once with one instruction, enabling you to make 16 additions in parallel.
Unless you are writing assembly code, you better make sure that your code is efficiently compiled to leverage the SIMD instruction set. This is being taking care of with the standard packages.

Your next speed up opportunities are in writing code to leverage multicore processors and to move your loops out of the interpreted python. Again, this is being taking care of with libraries and frameworks.

If you are a data scientist, you should only care about calling the right packages/frameworks, avoid reimplementing logic already offered by the libraries (with loops being a major example) and just focus on your application. If you are a framework/low-level code developer, you better learn the good coding practices or your package will never fly.

Answer (score 2):

> …why do people **keep referring** to vectorization as a coding practice that good coders leverage…?

Because in order to start seeing chances for **vectorisation** that requires a mental shift, to start seeing opportunities for it before one starts to architect any solution, choosing what Framework to use for doing so, or the code itself.

---

### *Is it SIMD ?*
Well *not* in the context in which you set the Question.

While compilers may permit an enforced transformation into SIMD-hardware plausible machine-code ( mentioned by [@B_F](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/users/8418325/b-f) ), it is most often not your option, when using an interpreted Python. Python modules may harness this low-level trick, if these were pre-compiled with such SIMD-enforced and/or other loop-avoiding options ( alike the `-O3` loop-unrolling *almost fanatic* code-transformations permit ).

Again, **not** your option during your code architecting, but a wise choice and re-use of hundreds of man*years experience of the engineering teams, who have dedicated their expertise and efforts into making Python modules harness the hardware to the max. Last, but not least, the SIMD-hardware is expensive, as it is decided and implemented in the silicon at some remarkable costs for the power-budget, clocking, processor micro-operations re-alignments, if in an out-of-order X-pipelined superscalar CISC processor specification.

Yet, SIMD-s can in principle do but several (vector-(small)-width aligned) V-FADD, V-FMUL, V-FMADD, some arcane width-directed boolean ops, so the machine-code transformations, that can & take place during the automated *( not manual, where people who indeed can do this job can achieve brutal speedups for one particular, and for obvious reasons typically in pretty important, HPC-alike & thus expensive use-cases )* SIMD-enforced compilation, are quite narrow-focused & limited in generality of such transformation.

While a manual conversion of a computation strategy can introduce SIMD-hardware instructions with a boots of end-to-end numerical-processing from a few days into ~ 12 minutes ( author was manually doing that for some time ), such task is principally out-of-range of automatic code-transformers, pre-coded in any of the compilers, that for obvious reasons restrict the scope and depth of the syntax-analysis and seek for some shallow, narrow-scope chances for SIMD-injection opportunities. The results of doing so are thus principally incomparable and not competing one the other ( who would ever like to do such hard-scratching and hair pulling job for the rest of their lives? ).

---

### Is it a `numpy[:]` syntax-sugar ?
Well, not either.
Numpy has *crafted* the vectorised-code approach for massive re-use among the Python user-base

The hat is to be raised for Numpy authors, for their opening this new concept for massive use in otherwise interpreted Python. The performance boost may impress us, yet the core benefit is not in the performance of execution of the vector/matrix/tensor-formulated operations.

**The core boost is in changing our way of thinking.**

Let me generalise a bit the view. Computer science is taught way later, than people start to code. Programming is most often (with bright & wise & very rare exceptions) presented as following some syntax rules, during a process of expressing our will to compute some thing ( be it a number or controlling a printing process et al ). This makes us start believe in an oversimplification, that it is just enough to start a series of steps, thinking in a serial-fashion, one-step-after-another, going from A-to-Z.

While this suffice for the beginning, sooner or later one gets to a point, that is not within such an easy concept achievable. Here the gang of tricks spins up ( be it a shift into event-driven frameworks, that emulate some sort of controlling concurrent execution in multiple stream of events, or functional-programming chains-of-dependence, allowing us not to think about the execution itself, but focus on the functionally-re-formulated problem description ).

All this requires a steep change of our mental view onto a computing strategy.

The same comes with efficient harnessing the vectorised code. You first have to realise the total change of the paradigm and start thinking in a non-**`[SERIAL]`** *( one-after-another-step-next-another-step )* manner.

---

### What is more *pythonic* v/s What is most important?

Forgive me not to step into this. Evangelisation is important for co-education of Task Force Teams, that need to share some culture of work. Outside of such a scope, this topic is not producing any added value and is prone to skew our valuable time & focus to pseudo-elitarian fights who is *"more"-pythonic* or *The Most-Pythonic* in one specific SLOC, whereas the art of doing smart business, or cutting-edge science, either one supported with contemporary computing powers, is by far not a point about styling whatever individual block-of-SLOCs.

Let's let these views for Evangelisators, who try to do their best in attempts to re-shape the otherwise wild and initially divergent crowd-force to at least not devastate as much some public work-in-progress in more-or-less spontaneous flow of developing design ideas and their iterative revisions of some future packages and/or maintaining the present or legacy ones.

---

### EPILOGUE :

- Vectorisation *per se* rewards one, if able to change one's mental view.
- Vectorisation is not just-SIMD-injection
- Vectorisation is not just-Numpy ( `numba` and other tools can harness this concept for the same smart-execution reasons as Numpy did "borrow" from FORTRAN/HPC-grade computing practices, and kept using FORTRAN-libs for many years since introduction, didn't it?)
- Vectorisation helps escape from a pure-`[SERIAL]` thinking about computation strategy, when same kind operations are to get executed "along"-the-whole Vector, "across"-the-whole Matrix, "through"-the-whole Tensor
- Vectorisation may permit a few smart-tricks in self-convoluted or striding-tricks related computation micro-strategies, where smart memory-access re-organisations may help better re-use pre-cached values ( at speeds ~ 100x faster, than re-fetching them again and again from main RAM ) - fell free to read whatever from The Masters - [@Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3293881%20%5Bnumpy%5D) or [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A901925%20%5Bnumpy%5D%20%5Bvectorization%5D) to see the examples, showing the actual powers of doing this to the limits
- Vectorisation is a general principle, yet its effects are dependent on the actual smartness & cleverness of the framework in use ( not an automatic property of the syntax - the implementation decides )
- Vectorisation is the more powerful, the more you can mathematically re-formulate the computation strategy under review, it is by far not just a loop-avoider **`:o)`** One can enforce Numpy to work in a vectorised fashion over a vector-of-objects, so not only the number-focused-crunching gets available, yet the effects of smart-cache re-uses and other Numpy strong powers (inherited from its FORTRAN fathers) would remain less super-efficient as they are in pure, memory-cells' aligned, cache-line optimised, number-crunching
- Vectorisation is nothing new - Thinking Machines did create vector-machines as early as in 1980-ies and CDC pioneered vector processors about two decades before them, so nothing new under the Sun, yet the above explained efficiency of automated ( machine driven ) code-transformations into vector decides about the level of performance boost in processing the results.
- Vectorisation so far (as of 2020-04) does not automatically step into using many-core / cross-core execution on NUMA-resources ( unless the package-authors hide the many-core work-splits over the NUMA-playgrounds from your, user-level view, which is not an easy step to do, is it? ), so do not overestimate the capabilities of ( machine/NUMA-dependent ) scheduling of the automated code-transformation into a localhost, yet NUMA-distributed, code-fragments' executions. Costs of doing this smart, universal & automatically are beyond my imagination ( and if there are some investors who would sponsor this, they most probably will not be willing to "share" the fruits of such their investments into general public use, will they? )